# Encoding error 2006 from Carto?

Tags: carto, encoding

When I want to upload a .zip-file of an ESRI-shapefile, I always get the encoding error 2006.
When I got this error the first time, I encoded the shapefile to UTF-8 in QGIS. Furthermore I uploaded the encoded shapes but the encoding error 2006 came again.

Does anyone know an answer?

I want to upload the zip file on the online mapping platform carto.com. For uploading georeferenced data, they need to be zipped.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Where are you uploading this zip file?  Even though you created this file using QGIS, once it is zipped, it becomes just like any non-GIS file.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your information. I want to upload the zip file on the online mapping platform carto.com. For uploading georeferenced data, they need to be zipped.

Comment: just guessing: maybe there are issues with your field names? can you share here the shapefile (even if it's just one feature for example)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't upload the shapefile. Can I do it in another way?

Comment: I think I got it. I generated the LOCK file (wasn't there before). Then I uploaded all zipped files to CARTO and the data appeared on the screen. **Thanks for your help!**